# how to copy file from /root of controller node to remote host's /root via ansible playbook

Tags: ansible, root, ansible-template

I need to copy a file from `/root` of ansible control node to remote node's `/root`.

I am able to copy that file if i keep it at any other location (say /tmp) of control node and able to copy it to /root of remote node (since i mentioned become in ansible.cfg )

But how to copy file from /root of ansible control node to remote node's /root ?

It gives error as

> 'fatal: [testserver]: FAILED! => {"changed": false, "msg": "Could not find or access '/root/abc.txt' on the Ansible Controller'

Please note, file exists at /root/ of controller.

thanks,

Comment: please paste your playbook

Answer (score 1):

To access a file in `/root` on the controller you need to be.... `root` on the controller. But running your playbook as root on the controller is not really a good idea. If your current user has the necessary rights on localhost for privilege escalation, a possible scenario would be.

1. use privilege escalation on `localhost` to copy the file or grab file content in a variable.
2. copy the resulting file or content to the target host.
3. if you copied the file, remove the copy.

Note: if you put the file in `/root` for privacy/security reasons, a much better option would be to store this file encrypted with [`ansible-vault`](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/user_guide/vault.html) directly in your project.